# Динамическая валидация POST на сайте

Tags: python, post, requests, postman

Возьмём условную страницу сайта, на ней есть форма для загрузки и отправки файла, а также некие скрытые поля, которые не отображаются на странице, но есть в коде, это inputы с типом hidden и в каждом из них в параметре value при обновлении страницы генерируется какая-либо строка валидации из случайных символов. Если мы загружаем файл и нажимаем кнопку отправить, то в request data в поля __VIEWSTATE и __EVENTVALIDATION добавляются значения этих валидаторов, вопрос таков, как через python, можно сгенерировать такой POST запрос? То есть я ведь не могу сначала GET запросом получить страницу сайта, взять оттуда валидаторы и далее POST запросом отправить файл с этими валидаторами, ведь они меняются при каждом обновлении страницы

Comment: Если валидаторы генерируются при каждом гет-запросе, то и при запросе через пайтон они также будут генерироваться, и ты будешь получать их в теле запроса

Comment: Нет, это понятно, я имел ввиду, что после обновления страницы, валидаторы для новой страницы, не будут валидными, вопрос в том, что если я получу валидаторы через гет запрос, то будут ли они валидными для пост запроса в той же сессии?

Comment: Что значит "после обновления страницы"? Обновление происходит не через GET запрос? Есть еще javascript который меняет эти скрытые поля?

Comment: Да, валидаторы есть в полученной гет запросом страничке, вопрос в том, будут ли они валидны для пост запроса, который будет следовать за гет запросом?